# find the limit : $\lim_{x\to 0} \left( \frac{x}{x-\sin x}-\frac{6}{x^2}\right)$

Tags: limits-without-lhopital

> Find the limit algebraically :
>
> $$\lim_{x\to 0} \left( \frac{x}{x-\sin x}-\frac{6}{x^2}\right)$$

My Try :

$$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{x^2}{x^2}\left( \frac{x}{x-\sin x}-\frac{6}{x^2}\right)$$

$$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{1}{x^2}\left( \frac{x^3}{x-\sin x}-6\right)$$

now:

$$\lim_{x\to 0} \left( \frac{x^3}{x-\sin x}\right)=6$$

So :

$$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{1}{x^2}\left( \frac{x^3}{x-\sin x}-6\right)=0$$

is it right ?

Comment: No.  $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to 0} \frac1{x^2} = +\infty$ and $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to 0} \left(\frac{x^3}{x-\sin x} - 6\right) = 0$, so the limit of their product is the indeterminate form $+\infty \cdot 0$, which isn't necessarily $0$.  Also, how'd you get $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{x^3}{x - \sin x} = 6$ without using l'Hopital?  I ask because this is currently tagged [tag:limits-without-lhopital].

Comment: Indeed the list of tools at your disposal and not at your disposal is most unclear at present, although this very much conditions the type of answer you are expecting.

Comment: I now see that this exact remark was made several times about some previous recent questions of yours. What makes that you are not hearing this message?

Answer (score -1):

HINT:
use $$\sin x =x-\frac{x^3}{3!}+\frac{x^5}{5!}-...$$so 
$$\lim_{x\to 0} \left( \frac{x}{x-\sin x}-\frac{6}{x^2}\right)=\\
\lim_{x\to 0} \left( \frac{x}{x-\left(x-\frac{x^3}{3!}+\frac{x^5}{5!}\right)}-\frac{6}{x^2}\right)=\\
\lim_{x\to 0} \left( \frac{x}{\frac{x^3}{3!}-\frac{x^5}{5!}}-\frac{6}{x^2}\right)=\\
\lim_{x\to 0} \left( \frac{1}{\frac{x^2}{3!}-\frac{x^4}{5!}}-\frac{6}{x^2}\right)=\\
\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{6}{x^2}\left( \frac{1}{1-\frac{x^2}{20}}-1\right)=\\$$can you go on  ?